# Robot legs- timer is service or model?

Tags: model-view-controller, service, model, timer, robotlegs

in [robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) can a Timer be inside a model or should it be encpsulated in a service.

Example:
lets say i'm implementing a digital clock in robot legs.
Should the Timer that updates the clock be a part of the ClockModel, 
or should it be in a TimerService the creates a command which updates the ClockModel?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [robotlegs best practices guide.](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/Best-Practices)

I will summarize but all the info is right there.

- [Model](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/Best-Practices#wiki-models) : used for storing internal application state
- [Service](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/Best-Practices#wiki-services) : used for storing state from external sources (db, rest service,..)

The distinction above is also made clear in the [robotlegs class diagram](http://www.robotlegs.org/diagram/)

So to answer you question, a Timer can be used in either a Service or a Model, depending on the context you are using it in.

Their best practices guide is really top notch and they also have a great [support forum](http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/) with loads of Q&A

I can really recommend you to go through [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021216.do)

Cheers